# What is the advantage of having a 'doctor europaeus' certified doctorate degree?

Tags: career-path, early-career, international, eu, degree

Universities in European Union countries have the possibility of issuing a PhD degree that is certified as "doctor europaeus" if the PhD student fulfills a certain [list of 4 requirements](http://spol.unica.it/dottorato/en/content/doctor-europ%C3%A6us), although [this university](http://artes.phil-fak.uni-koeln.de/19689.html?&L=1) reports a slightly different list of requirements.

Regardless of the requirements, **is there any advantage of having such certification**? I am referring to **practical advantages**, for example a certified degree can be accepted in other EU countries with less bureaucracy. And **career advantages** (for example more prestige or points gained in postdoc grant applications).

Comment: @MJeffryes that question asks what is a european doctorate, I want to know what and if there are any advantages, it's quite clear in my question.

Comment: The world, and also academia, is full of people who stop questioning anything if it's got the label "european" tagged to it, while those who still use their brains likely won't hold that extra title against you. So i guess the net effect will surely be positive.